# lagrangian multipliers proof

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I am not able to understand the theory behind the Lagrangian multipliers .

$f(x,y)$ is the function $g(x,y)$ is the constraint , then let 
$F(x,y)= f(x)- \lambda g(x,y)$

Now can someone please tell me what is the reasoning for assuming that  of $F(x,y)$ will have the same maxima and minima as the $f(x)$. Can anyone tell in simple terms the reasoning for this , I couldn't understand the explanation in the text book.

Comment: If the constraint is true then $F=f$ since $\lambda g=0.$

Comment: Even if the constraint is true how can we get just solve for x & y by just solving partial derivatives of F since x and y can be any two value,s even outside the domain set by constraint . What im asking is shouldnt we also have to solve partial derivative,s with the equation of constraint so as to make sure our solution is within the domain set by the constraint .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to understand the method of Lagrange multipliers by looking at $f$ and $g$ separately.

The constraint is expressed as $g(x,y)=\text{const}$, i.e., as a level curve of $g$. If we look at how $f$ changes along one of these curves, we see that at a stationary point, the directional derivative along a tangent to this curve vanishes, just as the derivative vanishes at a stationary point in the elementary one-dimensional case. This directional derivative is $\nabla f\cdot u$, where $u$ is tangent to the curve, so we must have that $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to the curve at this point.

On the other hand, the gradient of any differentiable function is orthogonal to its level curves, so at a stationary point $P$ of $f$ along the curve $g=\text{const}$, it must be the case that the two gradients are parallel, i.e., that $\nabla f(P)=\lambda\nabla g(P)$ for some constant $\lambda$. Note that at a different stationary point, $\lambda$ might also be different. Rearranging this condition gives the equation $$\nabla(f-\lambda g)=0\tag{1}$$ for the stationary points of the constrained function.

Sometimes the constraint is instead given as $g(x,y)=0$, with the constant absorbed into $g$. The above reasoning still holds, but now the constraint  can be folded into equation $(1)$ in the following way: Consider $F=f+\lambda g$ as a function of $\lambda$ as well as $x$ and $y$. Then $F_\lambda(x,y,\lambda) = g(x,y)$, so equation $(1)$ also encompasses the constraint $g=0$.